# SQL extract integer value from a long string

Tags: sql, regex, sap-iq

I have a table with `varchar(300)` (it containts some URLs) column, and I need to extract some value of this column to a new `integer` column.

**Source column:**

```
https://my_domain.com/?item1=value1&item2=value2&searching_field=int_value&item4=value4
```

I need to find string **`searching_field=int_value`** and insert `int_value` to a table.

**UPD**. I found a good tool `REGEXP_SUBSTRING` and I'm trying to use like below:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col_name, 'searching_field=[0-9]+', charindex('searching_field=', col)) as col from my_table
```

Comment: I guess the issue with your `REGEXP` is that it accounts for only one character. If say you want to substitute 3 characters(numbers), your `REGEXP` should be `'searching_field=[0-9][0-9][0-9]+&'`

Comment: Thanks for input but `'searching_field=[0-9]+'` works correctly for me.

Comment: [This][1] is the solution. I created it by my own


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28001029/4247360

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @occur_start INT;
DECLARE @occur_end INT;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE tempdb..#Temp
(col varchar(300), IntVal int)
```

---

```
INSERT INTO tempdb..#Temp
select col, SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('searching_field=', col), CHARINDEX('&item4=value4', col) - CHARINDEX('searching_field=', col)-1) IntValue
FROM YourTable
```

---

```
INSERT INTO YourOtherTable
SELECT IntValue FROM #Temp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... but I don't know the real values that go after `searching_field=int_value`... so it could be not `item4=value4`, it could be something else

Comment: Okay... let's asume that max length of my value is 10. Have to check it/