# SQL Anywhere Error -728: Update operation attempted on non-updatable remote query

Tags: sql, sql-update, sap-iq

What I'm trying to do:

```
update table_name set field2 = substring(REGEXP_SUBSTR(field1, 'item=[0-9]+', charindex('item=', field1)), 6)
```

But I'm getting

```
SQL Anywhere Error -728: Update operation attempted on non-updatable remote query
```

Can I solve it somehow? I don't use local/remote tables. I use one table.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299244/how-to-resolve-update-operation-attempted-on-non-updatable-query

Comment: This question doesn't solve problem. And sure I read the explanation at sybase site, but I need to update my table any way

Comment: Is your table a remote table?

Comment: I'm connecting to a sybase iq server by host:port, I guess table is not remote for a server, maybe it's remote for me (for my local machine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess I found soltion... even 2.
Unfortunately still no way to use REGEXP_SUBSTR...
I do:

**first**

```
alter table my_table add item_position int null
alter table my_table add is_char int null
alter table my_table add item_part varchar(200) null
alter table my_table add item bigint null    

update my_table set item_position = charindex('item=', field1)+5; 
update my_table set item_part = substring(field1, item_pos, 10); 
update my_table set is_char = charindex('&', clid_part)-1;     
update my_table set item = case when is_char = -1 then item_part else substring(item_part, 1, charindex('&', item_part)-1) end;
```

**or**

```
cast(str_replace(substring(field1, charindex('item=', field1)+5, 10), substring(substring(field1, charindex('item=', field1)+5, 10), 
(charindex('&', substring(field1, charindex('clid=', field1)+5, 10)))), '') as integer) as item
```

Something like this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to double check that table_name is actually a table, but not a view. If it is a view, you may see its definition with sp_helptext command, such as

> sp_helptext 'view_name'

or

> sp_helptext 'schema_name.view_name'